# GWT-VL FRAMEWORK

Tags: gwt, validation

I am trying to use the GWT-VL framework to validate my client side form.So as the first step i downloaded the .jar file  from sourceforge.net and imported it into my projects libraries.

Then i write a class which tries to use the validations.

The error which i get is  "**No source code is available for type eu.maydu.gwt.validation.client.ValidationProcessor; did you forget to inherit a required module?"**

So my question is does my class which uses the validation framework need to extend any class?

Or is there any problem with my importing the .jar file?
I think it should be not because i have added this .jar files to my libraries.

Or is there any other modification in need to make?

Also please suggest any other frameworks for validation of GWT-forms.I am just trying to integrate GWT-VL to play around with it and see if its convenient for usage.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the following line in your module.gwt.xml file:

```
<inherits name='eu.maydu.gwt.validation.ValidationLibrary' />
```

The class that uses the validation library does not have to extend a special class.

Answer (score 1):

You should update your module XML file, (modulename.gwt.xml) and add a reference to the framework you are using.. The required modification should be in the readme file of the downloads 90% of the time.